# Define a new key binding for font (Auctex)

Tags: key-bindings, auctex, fonts

I want to create a key binding like `C-c C-f C-c` to get `\mathscr{}` inside math environment. This is because there is no default key binding for getting `\mathscr`. How to do this? Remember that `C-c C-f C-c` is already in use to get  `\textsc` in the text mode.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Customize [`LaTeX-font-list`](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-LaTeX_002dfont_002dlist): <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `LaTeX-font-list` <kbd>RET</kbd>.  Select `Math Prefix:` for `^C` key (the prefix <kbd>C-c C-f</kbd> is omitted) and add `\mathscr{` to "Math Prefix:" field and `}` to "Math Suffix".